# How to preview a style before print dialog?

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm trying to show a preview of the print-styled page before the print dialog, by applying the print stylesheet to the screen stylesheet.

This doesn't work:

```
$('link[media*="screen"]').attr("href",url+"css/print/default.css");
window.print();
```

But with an alert() before the print(), it DOES work:

```
 $('link[media*="screen"]').attr("href",url+"css/print/default.css");
 alert("Ok?");
 window.print();
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function delays execution of `window.print` a few seconds (`delay` parameter, default about 5 seconds):

```
function doPrint(delay){
 delay = delay || 5; //default to 5 seconds
 $('link[media*="screen"]').attr("href",url+"css/print/default.css");
 setTimeout(function(){window.print();},delay*1000);
}
```

You could also restore the original css after the print dialog by putting the reverse of  `$('link[media*="screen"]').attr("href",url+"css/print/default.css");` into the function called from `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered this option: it works, but I have to choose the delay arbitrary, making this a not so elegant solution.

Comment: @kvwyns All right with me, but ehr, *I have to choose the delay arbitrary* means ...?

Comment: I meant I can't be sure that a 500ms delay will always work, so I have to make an educated guess. 
Thanks for the second tip (restoring the css): I overlooked this obvious possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call window.print() until you want to show the print dialog. Add another button to the page which the user can press to open the print dialog (this button may be hidden by default, shown when you show the preview, but don't forget to hide it again when printing!).

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to load a stylesheet. Without the alert, you are calling `print` before enough time has passed for the stylesheet to be loaded.

> Any hints?

Browsers have built in print and print preview functions. Avoid wheel reinvention.

Comment: Right of course, but to my knowledge the browsers print _preview_ can't be called from javascript? Also my favorite browser (chrome) simply doesn't give me one for now (12.0 dev).
We really need the preview: the stylesheet changes more then the user might suspect.

Comment: Chrome 12 / Mac has a print preview (on the print dialogue box as usual)